# Using Azure SAS URL download Blob (all files) once from Azure Blob Storage into Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Please can you help me understand? Is it possible to use the Azure SAS URL to download Blob(all files) once from Azure Blob Storage into Browser?
I mean can the user click generated SAS URL and it will download all files into my Browser as a Folder?
The problem that I have some time I have very large files I make them ZIP and want to put them into Azure Blob storage and give the user URL to click and download it as Folder ZIP, not as file one by one.
Or if you have another suggestion please let me know, if there are some solutions to do code level I can do it via C#.
Any help will be appreciated.

I can't download the azure blob using sas URL. I'm new in this space, if you have another solution in this case or another way please let me know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in 2 steps:

- Firstly, run a program that takes all the files in a blob storage container and places them in a zip file, store that zip file in another container.
- Then give the user a SAS URL to that file.